# Move object in array by index value in React native

Tags: react-native

So I have a `item` that is an object in my array state `items`.
I'm also getting the item-content (with its ID) and index of the current item into the function `indexMove`.

So `indexMove` is a function that is fired when I'm pressing a specific `item` from `items`.

My goal is that when `indexMove` is pressed the index number of the item decreases by 1 so it moves UP in the list. However the item at index 0 should just stop and not be able to move further up.

I really hope I'm being clear because it's a bit hard to explain, but how would I write this to change the items by index? Thank you

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])

const indexMove = (item, index) =>{
   console.log(item)
   console.log(index)
}
```

Comment: What should happen if we press on the item on the very top? Should nothing happen or should it be moved to the end insted?

Comment: Then nothing should happen,  so it stops at index 0, I'll update the post with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution using `FlatList` and a dummy state array.

```js
// just for test
React.useEffect(() => {
    // dummy data, some object with an id
    setItems([{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }, { id: "4" }, { id: "5" }, { id: "6" }])
  }, [setItems])

  const onItemClick = React.useCallback(
    (index) => {
      // do nothing on top element
      if (index !== 0) {
        let previousItems = [...items]
        let temp = previousItems[index - 1]
        previousItems[index - 1] = previousItems[index]
        previousItems[index] = temp
        setItems(previousItems)
      }
    },
    [setItems, items]
  )

  return (
   <View>
    <FlatList
            data={items}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 20 }} onPress={() => onItemClick(index)}>
                <Text>{item.id}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
   </View>
 )
```

which yields to the following

[image]

Pressing on item `3` moves it up.

[image]

It stops moving up until it reaches the very top, thus pressing the top element has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate the time you put into this explanation!

Comment: You are very welcome!